# Scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having a bit of trouble scraping certain fields in webpages. I have some code below that executes the 1st two for loops well but I am running into difficulty with the last for loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="https://www.mturk.com/mturk/findhits?match=false"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())


requesters=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'requesterIdentity'})
for eachrequester in requesters:
   print "Requester Name: "+eachrequester.string

rewards=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'reward'})
for eachreward in rewards:
   print "Reward: "+eachreward.string


hitnames=soup.findAll('a',{'class':'capsulelink'})  #THE ISSUE IS IN THESE 3 LINES
for eachhitname in hitnames:
   print "Hit Name: "+eachhitname.string
```

The code currently outputs:

```
Requester Name: Andrew Ryan
Requester Name: Vishwanath Kumar
Requester Name: rohzit0d
Requester Name: Jon Brelig
Requester Name: Tagasauris
Requester Name: Tagasauris
Requester Name: Tagasauris
Requester Name: CopyText Inc.
Requester Name: Tagasauris
Requester Name: Amazon Requester Inc.
Reward: $0.24
Reward: $0.03
Reward: $0.00
Reward: $0.05
Reward: $0.04
Reward: $0.02
Reward: $0.02
Reward: $0.01
Reward: $0.04
Reward: $0.00

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/pythonimageret/hitgwt.py", line 19, in <module>
    print "Hit Name: "+eachhitname.string
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

I realize that the script cannot find the contents of the html here. The HTML looks like:

```html
<a class="capsulelink" href="#" id="capsule6-0">
    Indoors or Out?
    <span class="tags"></span>
</a>
```

I think it is because `href="#" id="capsule6-0"` are in between the `class=""` and the `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eachhitname.string` is `None` because that attribute only contains text if there are no other tags in the current element. Each of those links have a `<span class="tags"></span>` element.

Use the `.text` attribute instead; adding in a `str.strip()`call to remove the extra whitespace:

```
hitnames = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'capsulelink'})
for eachhitname in hitnames:
   print "Hit Name: " + eachhitname.text.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks so much worked perfectly and I understand why. (sry I can't upvote I don't have a good enough reputation yet)